# Repeat the playing of an mp4 file

Tags: omxplayer

Using omxplayer I want to repeat the playing of a 2 minute mp4 file for about 30 minutes.
I could do this by using a for-While loop, but there is about a half second display of the terminal between each loop.

I also tried the -loop option on OMP and the no-osd option which would work if I could stop the looping after 30 minutes.

Any Advice???
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use Will Price's OMXPlayer Wrapper for omxplayer

Comment: At the very least you should have provided a link.

Comment: https://github.com/willprice/python-omxplayer-wrapper